# Mouse Cursor Blob in Acemovi Editor Screen Recording

Tags: mouse, screen-recorder

In playing back a movie made with the Acemovi Editor Screen Recorder, the existing mouse cursor is surrounded by a semi-opaque large yellow round mouse cursor which may partially hide or conceal objects or text behind it. The mouse is using a Windows Black extra large system scheme, tried with other pointers, no change. Tested the effect with a licensed copy of AceMovi by recording screen activity on two separate machines. A short video of the effect at [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx4Nj8Zd7tg).

[image: Blob around mouse cursor]

There doesn't appear to be anything in the program preferences to change it, and the support team apparently have no knowledge of it. Do others experience this, and if so, can we conclude it's an inbuilt feature in the software?

Answer (score 0):

Found the Recording Preferences. The blob is the default setting in the Mouse tab.

[image: Recording Preferences]

It is documented, but under [Import-Media](https://acemovi.tuneskit.com/guide/import-media.html), and down the page. In the gui, there's no menu item for the recording preferences, but a gear on the recording box- have submitted a request to make it more visible somehow.